# I have a string "$1,285.00" to convert into number by using javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I would like to convert a string "$1,258.98" into a number 1258.98.  How to use JavaScript to achieve this purpose?

Comment: by searching the internet?

Answer (score 1):

1. Simply replace `$` and `,` in the string with empty string and then use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function to convert it to a valid floating point number.

   ```
   var data = "$1,258.98";
   console.log(parseFloat(data.replace("$", "").replace(",", "")));
   ```
2. Or replace just the `,` and then ignore the first character with `substring(1)` like this

   ```
   console.log(parseFloat(data.replace(",", "").substring(1)));
   ```
3. Or you can use regular expression, to replace `$` and `,`, like this

   ```
   console.log(parseFloat(data.replace(/[$,]/g, "")));
   ```

**Output**

```
1258.98
```